# How to create layout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create a layout with buttons arranged in the following manner. Please explain how I can create such a layout.

```
-----------------------------------
|  b1  |  b2 |  b3  |  b4  |  b5  |
-----------------------------------





--------                   --------
|  b6  |                   |  b7  |
--------                   --------





--------------------------------------
|  b8  |  b9 |  b10  |  b11  |  b12  |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Read basic android tutorials.

Comment: One Relative, two Linear, twelve Button. Align to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, the center RelativeLayout is not necessary, you can just add android:layout_centerInParent="true" property to the two buttons and leave the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutBase"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For similar objectives the Graphical Layout Designer of the IDE is a good starting point also.

I hope it helps!